# Curl php não esta funcionando

Tags: php, libcurl

estou usando curl php no servidor.

```
function getSite($url){
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    echo curl_error($ch);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);   
    echo $output;
}

getSite("http://www.google.com.br");
getSite("http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/Constituicao/Constituicao.htm");
```

O site do google funciona perfeitamente mas o site do planalto não. Em localhost os 2 funcionam.
O que pode estar acontecendo?
Os 2 sites são externos mas só um funciona (o link do site do planalto está correto mas nem erro do curl mostra )
desde já agradeço

Comment: Testa adicionar mais curl_setopt, pelo menos o básico. Ignore o SSL/CA, usando `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` e `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)`, adicione para seguir redirecionamento usando `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)`, adicione um USER_AGENT, usando, por exemplo: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`. Se isso resolver posso explicar melhor numa resposta. ISSO É PARA TESTE! Se isso não resolver o IP pode está bloqueado, ou fator externo,TESTE COM PROXY

Comment: esta dando o seguinte erro com os itens que pediu pra adcionar

Comment: esta dando o seguinte erro com os itens que pediu pra adcionar  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set .Retirando o CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION continua do mesmo jeito ,estou achando que o meu servidor de hospedagem esta bloqueando o site o planalto. Isso e possível?

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o site do planalto tem uma verificação de user agent para responder... fazendo o curl a partir da minha máquina ele não funciona porém passando um user agent de browser ele responde corretamente.

Ex via terminal:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5" http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/Constituicao/Constituicao.htm
```

Com php seria setar:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5");
```

Comment: Valeu, mas o problema foi no servidor da minha hospedagem,arrumou mas não me disseram o que aconteceu.